# select images randomly from drawable

Tags: android

I have a number of images in drawable folder. How to show images randomly from drawable?

Comment: Show images where? Do you mean select images randomly and display in a Drawable?

Comment: With respect, do you think you could have taken just two seconds to re-read your post and fix the blatant typos? The more effort you put into your question, the better the quality and quantity of answers you'll get. Separately, this question is too vague and open-ended to really be answerable. (This may have been the issue with your other unanswered question as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Put you image IDs in an int array and then generate a random number between 0 and length - 1